# What does ClassName < :: imply in ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I saw this line of code.

```
class ClassName < ::TestUnit::Test::Etc
```

What does it mean when the nested-constant marker follows the inheritance symbol, like so: `< ::SuperClass`?

Also, is there a technical name for the `::` symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator. It means "look up the following constant name inside this module". If you omit the module, it is assumed to be `Object`. So, `::Foo` is basically the same as `Object::Foo` except of course that the enclosing module may define its *own* `Object` constant, in which case the second form would look up `Foo` inside *that* `Object` instead of the one you expect it to.

Note that `::` can *also* be used as the message sending operator, i.e. the same way as `.`: `foo::bar` is the same as `foo.bar`. This usage is *highly* discouraged, though.

Comment: Just so I've got this right, it is a directive saying 'Look for this constant inside of the current class/module scope?

Comment: No, `Foo::Bar` means "look up constant `Bar` in `Foo`". If you leave out `Foo` it is assumed to be `Object`. If you want to look up `Foo` in the *current* scope, you simply say `Foo`. You only need the scope resolution operator if you do *not* want to look in the current scope. It works exactly the same as similar operators in other areas, for example the `/` operator in filesystem path lookup.

Comment: Ok, so it is similar to `../` in UNIX?

Comment: No, it is similar to `/` in Unix.